# Git unable to write sha1 filename...fatal: failed to write commit object

Tags: git, rstudio

I've installed git (version 2.19.0.windows.1). I am trying to **commit** changes that I did in Rstudio, I am trying to commit in Git in Rstudio and in GitBash and everywhere I get the same errors.

First error is:

```
$ git commit --all -m 'Test 6'
fatal: couldn't set 'refs/heads/branchName'
```

After I am trying to resolve problem and I always get next error:

```
$ git commit --all -m 'Test 6'
error: unable to write sha1 filename .git/objects/2a/2efc0c4ac6c8c69e78c5555a1a2e5c21d2f3c1: Function not implemented
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I've tried:

1. git config --global core.fscache false
2. wait and repeat $ git commit few times..

and always it helps, but just for one time, next time I try to commit again and I get the same errors. Could you please help me and tell me, why I have this errors and how I can resolve them?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like your local `.git` directory is not writable. Check if you can create an empty file, like `test.txt`, inside your working directory’s `.git` folder.

Comment: I can create an empty file in .git folder (folder with files config, HEAD, FETCH_HEAD and etc.) :(

Comment: Did you try to create another working directory elsewhere on the drive and see if it works there, in case you got a corrupted disk?

Comment: "Function not implemented" suggests that you're using a broken file system. Try using a native OS file system, rather than whatever it is that you are using (some kind of Samba server or network drive?).

Comment: @LeviHaskell, I cloned git on another disk and it helped me! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @torek it looks like that I used a broken disk, I cloned git on another disk and it helped me! Thank you very much! :)